# Is there any algorithm we can use for correlation for my problem?

Tags: python, image, numpy, scipy, correlation

[image: Grid Image with 275 points]

How can we precisely find a max correlation of every point of these grid images(275 points)?
How can we correlate 100 photos of this image to calculate the displacement?
I use Python programming(OpenCV, Numpy, Scipy, etc.)

I have used the pearsonr function to correlate the image; I need to figure out how to correlate with every grid point image by image and calculate the displacement.

Comment: You can't calculate the correlation of X, you can only ask what the correlation of X with something else is. What's the "something else" in this case?